# Is it possible to make part of a graph white in pylab?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to make a 3D captcha using `pylab`, `PIL.ImageFont`, `PIL.Image`, `PIL.ImageDraw` `numpy` and a couple others. For the most part it seems to work.Examples:
http://puu.sh/dft1a/1d35f5c99a.png
http://puu.sh/dfuat/f35fa6d155.jpg

What I would like to be able to do is to have the option to make z=0 be white, that is to remove the color that is not part of the text. Is this possible?

I've tried setting Axes3D.plot_surface(alpha=.2, linewidth=0) and it results in this:
http://puu.sh/dfupq/223ad49403.jpg

Although that's closer to what I want I would like to just remove the background color in general and only have the text color remaining

This is the main portion that creates the 3D text:

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((text_width, text_height), text, font=font)

fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(width/100.0, height/100.0), dpi=4000)
axes = Axes3D(fig)
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(range(img.size[0]), range(img.size[1]))
Z = 1 - numpy.asarray(img) / 255 if not hard else 50

if hard:
    func = Axes3D.plot_wireframe
else:
    func = Axes3D.plot_surface if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else Axes3D.plot_wireframe

func(axes, X, -Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, color=_rand_color())

axes.set_zlim((-3, 3))
axes.set_xlim((text_width * 1.1, text_width * 1.9))
axes.set_ylim((-text_height * 1.9, -text_height* 1.1))
axes.set_axis_off()
axes.view_init(elev=60, azim=-90+angle)
```

If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!